oninit functions are not working in flutter using get CLI
I recently created an app with Get cli structure and now when i'm trying to use oninit functions they are not working and the only way i could fix it was to use Get builder but my app has too many pages that i can't replace them all does anyone know what is causing these functions not to work?
Binding:
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../controllers/login_controller.dart';

class LoginBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<LoginController>(
      () => LoginController(),
    );
  }
}


Controller:
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class LoginController extends GetxController {
  //TODO: Implement LoginController

  final count = 0.obs;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    print('but i work fine');
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();
  }

  void increment() => count.value++;
}


View:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../../../routes/app_pages.dart';
import '../controllers/login_controller.dart';

class LoginView extends GetView<LoginController> {
  const LoginView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'EVIDENCIA',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 32,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 8),
                Text(
                  'Evidence based history taking',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                Text(
                  'be with us',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black87,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 32),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Username',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Password',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                  obscureText: true,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 24),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {

                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    minimumSize: Size(double.infinity, 50),
                  ),
                  child: Text('login'),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 24),
                Text(
                  'evidencia.com',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Get.offAndToNamed(Routes.REGISTER);
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'register',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}


The way it works :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../../../routes/app_pages.dart';
import '../controllers/login_controller.dart';

class LoginView extends GetView<LoginController> {
  const LoginView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<LoginController>(
        init: LoginController(),
    builder: (controller) {
      return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'EVIDENCIA',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 32,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8),
                  Text(
                    'Evidence based history taking',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      color: Colors.black54,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  Text(
                    'be with us',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black87,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 32),
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Username',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Password',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                    obscureText: true,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 24),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {

                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      minimumSize: Size(double.infinity, 50),
                    ),
                    child: Text('login'),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 24),
                  Text(
                    'evidencia.com',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      color: Colors.black54,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.offAndToNamed(Routes.REGISTER);
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'register',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });


  }
}


any help would be appreciated.
this is the get builder
GetBuilder<LoginController>(
  init: LoginController(),
  builder: (controller) {})


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I'm not entirely sure but I think the problem is that you don't have a single reference to the controller in your code. It is lazily initiated and will only be created once you reference it.
Like changing these lines
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

to for example
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(controller.count);
    return Scaffold(

might work

this worked but i just changed the lazy put into normal and then made it to delete the page from onclose function
